# Regex in Java use same group in alternative matches

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have a regex pattern which matches different expressions but i want both matches to be in the same capturing group.
Currently i got the following regex:

```
-([^\s"]+)|-"(.+?)"
```

This does in fact match both (-hello -"Hello World") but in different groups (-hello = group1 and "Hello World" = group2).

In fact I got a working example, which is unfortunately not possible in Java regex:

```
(?|-([^\s"]+)|-"(.+?)")
```

Comment: Branch reset groups are not supported in Java regex. Use your regex, and some code to detect which group is not null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use look around assertion so you can get rid of all capture groups and get full match in result:

```sh
(?<=-)[^\s"]+|(?<=-")[^"]*(?=")
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nMvmBD/1)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=-)[^\\s\"]+|(?<=-\")[^\"]*(?=\")");

List<String> res = p.matcher("(-hello -\"Hello World\")")
        .results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

//=> [hello, Hello World]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a regex pattern matcher and check both capture groups, using whichever one is not null:

```java
String input = "-hello -\"Hello World\"";
String pattern = "-([^\\s\"]+)|-\"(.+?)\"";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    String match = !Objects.isNull(m.group(1)) ? m.group(1) : m.group(2);
    System.out.println("Found a match: " + match);
}
```

This prints:

```
Found a match: hello
Found a match: Hello World
```